# Where can I learn about a history of holes?

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, history, quasiparticles, charge-carrier

Holes are quasiparticles that were historically brought to explain semiconductor physics with extra benefit of simplifying the counting of electrons.Who gave the first idea and how did it develop gradually?I searched in the internet,wiki(or other sites)do not have any history section on holes.Where can I find a historical treatment of holes in semiconductors?

Comment: I would simply look up a history of semiconductors and see the theory section there. Such as here: https://djena.engineering.cornell.edu/hws/history_of_semiconductors.pdf.